# passing tables in json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I was trying to pass tables using JSON as shown below.

**sample.json**

```
 {       
     "title": "sample data",
     "body": "<table border=\"1\" width=\"600\" bordercolor=\"#FFFFFF\"><tr><td>Column 1</td> <td>Column 2</td></tr></table>"
 }
```

I used Javascript code to read the JSON file,

```
 $.getJSON("sample.json", function(data) {
     console.log(data);
 });
```

But generates the following error

[JAVASCRIPT ERROR]

Error Detail : TypeError: body is undefined

Is it possible to pass tables in JSON?

Comment: This should work. Your problem must be elsewhere, for example in the use of the data.

Comment: How are you looking for body?

Comment: _What_ says body undefined? Because it's no code you've pasted here, that's for sure.

Comment: You can pass tables or cookies (the eatable ones) or unicorns... as long as it is encoded as a valid value in JSON, it's fine. Your "table" seems to be a string containing HTML and strings are valid values. Please explain your problem better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error lies somewhere else. The following jsfiddle proves that it works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/YYPHe/

I removed the quotes around attributes just to avoid the escaping problems. It may be that your code is not properly escaping your quotes.

```
var json = '{"title": "sample data","body": "<table border=1 width=600 bordercolor=#FFFFFF><tr><td>Column 1</td> <td>Column 2</td></tr></table>"}';

$.ajax({
    url: "/echo/json/", 
    data: {
        json: json 
    },
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
       console.log(data.body);
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling `body` on your code, when are you calling this?

```
 $.getJSON("sample.json", function(data) {
     console.log(data.body);
 });
```